# Interactive Controls (switches, knobs, buttons) in Unity

Tags: unity, gui, control

I'm working on a puzzle aspect of a game, and wanted to make a section where players relay information to one another, and have to input the correct values.

At its most basic, its a few stored variables that exist only for this, and really don't do anything. i.e. "Turn on shields" would just be a bool. "Set phasers to 5" an int. etc.

I'm trying to figure out the best way for a player to interact with these variables. I've considered GUI elements placed on gameobjects, but I'm not entirely comfortable with Unity's GUI system.

Should i take the time and use the GUI system, or would setting up my own scripts to edit the controls (toggle boxes, sliders, knobs) be a more simple solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This question can be considered opinion based so I'm going to give you my opinion. If you have some sort of deadline then go with the approach you feel more comfy with. But if you do not have a deadline I suggest that you take your time and learn how to use the UI system. After version 4.6 they made it way better and easy to use. Eventually you will have to use it in a project and its better to learn new stuff now than when you actually need it. Besides the UI system is incredibly powerful, I've made entire mini-games with it.